# Tools /framework for prototyping website supporting multiple devices

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, html, web-applications

I want to create a web portal that can be loaded on multiple devices primarily phones [just android or iphone is fine too] and desktop browsers.

I am trying to prototype a product idea I did some research about. I want to build a minimal viable product, that I can give to friends to use, use for demo etc and iterate on it eventually..

Since currently I am the only person/dev on the team [4 hours per week] , here are my primary requirements:

1. Should have less learning curve and get me off to start
2. Doesn't need to be generic but should satisfy atleast a subset well. [ex works on browser and iphone [ipad, android phone] only is fine
3. Good community support and easy to find people to work with.
4. Performance is not a big concern
5. Native code or look is not a big concern
6. I expect primary users to be phone users , but limited functionality on phone is fine for now.
7. I dont mind throwing the entire thing and rewrite something in a better way eventually after I have some traction.

HTML5 web pages can be loaded on multiple devices [?] so something like that is fine.

I have mostly been an backend dev [Java, ruby, DBs, solr, lucene, memcache etc] so I am not proficient with web tech [jscript, jquery, css, ajax] etc which makes this tricky. I know ruby and am trying to learn rails [ learning cucumber, capybara etc] and am finding it very user friendly and quick for prototyping

Any [list of] tools / frameworks out there that help to build such portal. Since I am using ruby and rails more everyday would love something from that eco-system but not necessary.

Thanks.
P.S: The portal is a small ecommerce like site that interface with different ecommerse websites and  users social feeds etc to bring them some recommendations [For now thinking about comparison shopping portal is fine]

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend following a [responsive design](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/) approach using CSS media queries.

This way you don't worry about anything native or which device. Just focus on CSS and HTML.

Basically you build with a mobile first approach and then using media queries, you enhance the layout (and / or functionality) as the device screen size increases.

Have a look at [this list of frameworks](http://webexpedition18.com/articles/responsive-css-frameworks/) that can help. I've used 320 and up, LESS and Amazium. Pick one that suits what you need.

Here are some [common patterns](http://designshack.net/articles/css/5-really-useful-responsive-web-design-patterns/) in responsive design.

Here's a [gallery](http://mediaqueri.es/) of great responsive designs.

Comment: Thanks for the list and the edit to question. Will try out a few  and wait for few more responses before accepting